# Get a node within a node in XML file, using Javascript

Tags: javascript, xml

I have an XML file, "Fixtures", and I am trying to get all of the fixtures within the "irelandGames" section. I can go through and 'manually' select the fixtures, but surely there is a better way, rather than me having to actually know the exact position of every item in the file.

Here is the XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<fixtures>
  <irelandGames>
    <md1>
      <date>13</date>
      <time>17</time>
      <location>Stade de France</location>
      <teams>Ireland V Sweden</teams>
    </md1>
    <md2>
      <date>18</date>
      <time>14</time>
      <location>Stade de Bordeaux</location>
      <teams>Belgium V Ireland</teams>
    </md2>
    <md3>
      <date>22</date>
      <time>20</time>
      <location>Stade Pierre Mauroy</location>
      <teams>Italy V Ireland</teams>
    </md3>
  </irelandGames>

<italyGames>
    <md1>
      <date>13</date>
      <time>20</time>
      <location>Stade de Lyon</location>
      <teams>Belgium v Italy</teams>
    </md1>
    <md2>
      <date>17</date>
      <time>14</time>
      <location>Stade de Toulouse</location>
      <teams>Italy V Sweden</teams>
    </md2>
  <md3>
      <date>22</date>
      <time>20</time>
      <location>Stade Pierre Mauroy</location>
      <teams>Italy V Ireland</teams>
    </md3>
  </italyGames>
</fixtures>
```

Here is the code I've used to retrieve Ireland fixtures:

```
var xmlDoc = xhttp.responseXML;
var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("teams");
console.log("x: " + x.length);

var i;
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    irelandMatches.push(x[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
}
```

As you can see, for me to get Italy's fixtures, I could code it get "teams" 3 to 5, however, this seems very messy. Is there a way to get it to retrieve all "teams" from, like "irelandGames" rather than having to number each node.

Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just target the tags for the countries before you get the teams

```
var xmlDoc = xhttp.responseXML;

var country = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("irelandGames");
var teams   = country[0].getElementsByTagName("teams");

var irelandMatches = [];

for (var i=0; i<teams.length; i++) {
    irelandMatches.push(teams[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
}
```

Comment: I'm getting this error: "TypeError: country.getElementsByTagName is not a function"  - any suggestions? :)

Comment: Yes, use `country[0].getElementsByTagName("teams")`